# How can I compare two List and match it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list, comparison

I have two list, one with the master data and one with the wrong data. So now I want to compare this thow list and match the wrong one to the right one.

```
 public class Data
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text{ get; set; }
}

var masterList = new List<Data> { new Data { id = 1, Text = "Hello" }, new Data() {id = 2, Text ="Ciao"} };
var wrongList = new List<Data> { new Data { id = 1, Text = "Ciao" }, new Data() {id = 2, Text ="Morning"} };
```

Now in the masterList the Text for id 1 is "Hello", and in the wrongList the  text with the id 1 is "Ciao".

But the text with id 2 has the Text "Hello", so how can I match this two list, when there is a match in the list, that I get the right Text to the right Id...

if the text match, then I will have a new List as follow:

id = 2, Text = "Ciao"

I hope you understand my question!

thanks for any help...

Comment: what is expected result in your given example

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: The expected output from the example is simply the contents of `masterList`.  What comparison even needs to be performed?

Comment: @user1861065 - Now I'm even more confused..

Comment: what happens if something does not exist in wrongList? you should give example which outputs different results so we can understand why you even need wrongList

Comment: then nothing, I must have only the matching text with the id

Comment: @user1861065: `var matches = masterList;` - Like that?  Seriously, there's no logic to implement here.  At least not according to the example given.

Comment: @David, when i have in the wrong list for id 2 this text "Morning" then I will have the following result: id = 2 , Text = "Ciao"... not more...

Comment: @user1861065: Nope, that one line of code in my previous comment which produces the result you described in the question wouldn't be affected at all by *any* entries in `wrongList`.  If you have any code which actually produces an incorrect result and a question to ask regarding the behavior of that code, feel free to include it in your question.  As it stands now, your question makes no sense.

Comment: yeah this line of code, which you gave in your comment doesn't help me. And consider, for your helpful code, I would never ask such a question!

Comment: @user1861065: If you could elaborate on the question perhaps somebody can be of more help.  Currently that one line of code produces the desired result for all examples and descriptions provided so far.  If there are further problems which you *haven't* described, then try to understand that we can't read your mind.

Comment: There's not a simple one-line solution.  You can define "equality" for two `Data` objects (either within that class or through an `IEqualityComparer` and use `SequenceEquals` or some other Linq query, or you can just loop through the master list, looking for an item with the same  `Text` property.  Try that and come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with linq and `Intersect` and making `Data` implement `IEquatable<Data>`.

```
var matches = masertList.Intersect(wrongList);
```

**UPDATE**: As per comments, here is a solution implementing an `IEqualityComparer<Data>`

```
class DataComparer : IEqualityComparer<Data>
{
    // Datas are equal if their names and Id are equal.
    public bool Equals(Data x, Data y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) ||
            ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Text == y.Text;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Data data)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(product, null))
            return 0;

        return (product.Name == null ? 0 : product.Name.GetHashCode()) ^ product.Code.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And now, youd simply do: `var matches = masertList.Intersect(wrongList, new DataComparer());`

Comment: with this I get following error: Enumeration yielded no results

Comment: That's because classes use _reference_ equality by default.  Since your lists contain different objects (some of which happen to have the same property values) the intersection will be empty.

Comment: @user1861065 `Data` needs to implement `IEquatable<Data>` according to your needs. Or you can implement a custom `IEqualityCompararer<Data>` and use the corresponding overload of `Intersect`.